# Windows 10 on external drive through boot camp

Tags: bootcamp, windows, usb, ssd, external-disk

I've installed Windows 10 on external drive (SSD through USB) on a previous Macbook pro and it was working fine. I bought a new one now, but that same external drive doesn't boot anymore. Instead it says:

> Unable to verify startup disk

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install and boot Windows from USB hard drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5415/install-and-boot-windows-from-usb-hard-drive)

Comment: Alternatively https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355318/bootcamp-hdd-is-now-in-a-usb3-external-enclosure-can-i-boot-my-imac-from-it?rq=1 which shows a way

Comment: So this is a duplicate byt of what we have two different answers yes and no.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I have Win 10 installed already which was working with a previous Macbook. Now I want to connect it to my new one, but doesn't boot... Also I don't want to install from scratch as that (along with moving the data) would take a lot of time.

Comment: Hmm, actually - will give it a go tomorrow, and will see. Thanks @Mark